# Toolbar options in Action bar? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, mobile

Is there some way to show toolbar options in action bar? Such that:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to add sharing options when a text is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`AppBar` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) has an [`actions` property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/actions.html) that can be used:

[image]

Just fill it when you detect a text selection with an array of [`IconButton`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html).

Check out this DartPad gist: https://dartpad.dev/70fde86853b9ef9d957507f2f4aef0b3!

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the code below :

[image][image]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Choice _selectedChoice = choices[0]; // The app's "state".

  void _select(Choice choice) {
    setState(() { // Causes the app to rebuild with the new _selectedChoice.
      _selectedChoice = choice;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Basic AppBar'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // action button
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(choices[0].icon),
            onPressed: () {
              _select(choices[0]);
            },
          ),
          // action button
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(choices[1].icon),
            onPressed: () {
              _select(choices[1]);
            },
          ),
          // overflow menu
          PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
            onSelected: _select,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return choices.skip(2).map((Choice choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice.title),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: ChoiceCard(choice: _selectedChoice),
  ),
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({ this.title, this.icon });
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = <Choice>[
  Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({ Key key, this.choice }) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(choice.icon, size: 128.0, color: textStyle.color),
            Text(choice.title, style: textStyle),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope This will help you !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `actions`-Property from `AppBar` to put in some options in your toolbar.
Here is an example I got from the Flutter docs:

```
home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Basic AppBar'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // action button
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(choices[0].icon),
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[0]);
              },
            ),
            // action button
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(choices[1].icon),
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[1]);
              },
            ),
```

https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/basic-app-bar